# The correct way to change the base class from derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns

I am trying to design several base drawing classes from which I can inherit and define complex drawings. In the code below, you can see that `LineDrawing` and `CompoundDrawing` derive from an abstract `Drawing` class. The `CompoundDrawing` class has an internal `List<Drawing>` that allows us to store multiple `Drawing` objects and define complex drawings.

```
public abstract class Drawing
{       
    public bool CanBeRotated 
    {
       get; 
       set;
    }

    private float m_rotation;
    public float Rotation
    {
        get 
        { 
           return m_rotation;
        }
    }

    protected Drawing()
    {
        CanBeRotated = true;
    }

    public void Rotate(float degree)
    {
        if (CanBeRotated)
            m_rotation = degree;
    }
}

public sealed class LineDrawing : Drawing
{
    private readonly Line m_line;

    public Line Line
    {
        get
        {
           return m_line;
        }
    }

    public LineDrawing(Line line)
    {
        m_line = line;
    }
}

public class CompoundDrawing : Drawing
{
    protected IList<Drawing> m_drawings;

    protected CompoundDrawing(IList<Drawing> drawings)
    {
        m_drawings = new List<Drawing>(drawings);
    }
}
```

Now I want to define a `RectangleDrawing` class that derives from `CompoundDrawing`. Here is the code for this class:

```
public class RectangleDrawing : CompoundDrawing
{
    public RectangleDrawing(IList<LineDrawing> lineDrawings) : base(lineDrawings)
    {
        foreach(var line in lineDrawings)
        {
            line.CanBeRotated = false;
        }
    }    
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the `LineDrawing` objects in the `RectangleDrawing` class should not be rotatable, but I'm not sure where in my design pattern I should set this restriction. How can I prevent the `LineDrawing` objects in `RectangleDrawing` from being rotatable?

Comment: So you don't want `RectangleDrawing` to be rotated or the composing line segments?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET The line segments!

Comment: I guess you would just do a foreach of `lineDrawings` and set their `CanBeRotated` property. Or change your inheritance model so that each class is either always rotatable or not.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Is it a good design to change the lines from derived class?

Comment: You are composing `LineDrawing` not deriving from it; I don't see an issue.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET But I'm deriving from Compund Drawing and the list of drawings is in that class! :s

Comment: So what? You're still composing the class. If your basic question is "Can derived classes touch base class members" the answer is a resounding *yes*.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks I do not know why I'm having doubts tonight :D

Comment: @Vahid `public RectangleDrawing(IList<LineDrawing> lineDrawings) : base(lineDrawings)` wouldn't compile anyway as `IList<T>` is an invariant interface

Comment: You still need to rotate the lines in order to rotate the rectangle. If you set the property to `false` then you'd need to reset it temporarily back to `true` again when rotating the rectangle. I think your whole set up is simply too complicated and it's working against you instead of helping.

Comment: It seems to me that whatever the `CompoundDrawing` might be, you will never want to rotate any of the `m_drawings`. Am I right? If so, you might want consider a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider taking an immutable approach:

```
public abstract class Drawing
{ 
    //some shapes might not be rotable or rotation
    //simply doesn't make sense: circle      
    public virtual bool CanBeRotated => true;

    public Drawing Rotate(float degree)
    {
        //Don't mutate this, return a new
        //rotated instance.
        if (!CanBeRotated) return this;
        return rotate(float);
    }

    //let each concrete type handle its own rotation.
    protected abstract Drawing rotate(float);

    //etc.
}
```

What does immutability buy you? Well, who cares if someone tries to rotate and individual line of your compound object? They won't change anything significant because nothing can change, they will simply obtain a *new* rotated line that doesn't belong to the original compound object.

And the `CompoundDrawing` rotation logic would be rather simple:

```
protected override Drawing rotate(float degeee)
   //Note I'm passing in an IEnumerable<Line> instead of an IList<>
   //Why the need of an IList<>, don't burden the API with unecessary 
   //constraints.
    => new Rectange(lines.Select(l => l.Rotate(degree)));
```

All this said, I'd recommend you change your building block to `Point`, `Line` seems like a weird choice. This way all shapes are compound drawings made up of points in a specific order. Drawing any shape is simply connecting the points in order, rotating is simply rotating every point, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd move the Rotate to its own interface since it wouldn't be valid for all kinds of drawing.

```
public interface IRotate
{
    void Rotate(float degree);
}

public class SquareDrawing : Drawing, IRotate
{
    public void Rotate(float degree)
    {
         //actual code to rotate the drawing
    }
}

public class RectangleDrawing : CompoundDrawing
{
     public RectangleDrawing(IList<LineDrawing> lineDrawings) : base(lineDrawings)
     {
        foreach(var line in lineDrawings)
        {
            if (line is IRotate)
            {
                 ((IRotate)line).Rotate(45.0);
            }
        }
     }    
}
```